# Access class constant dynamically through dataProvider with PHPUnit 5.5.4

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit, php-7

I have a bunch of class constants that I would like to check the value of in my PHPUnit test.

When I run this test I get the following error:

> 1) CRMPiccoBundle\Tests\Services\MailerTest::testConstantValues with
>   data set "Account Verification" ('ACCOUNT_VERIFICATION',
>   'CRMPicco.co.uk Account Verification') Error: Access to undeclared
>   static property: CRMPiccoBundle\Services\Mailer::$constant

This is my test and its corresponding dataProvider:

```
/**
 * @dataProvider constantValueDataProvider
 */
public function testConstantValues(string $constant, $expectedValue)
{
    $mailer = new Mailer();
    $this->assertEquals($expectedValue, $mailer::$constant);
}

public function constantValueDataProvider()
{
    return [
        'Account Verification' => [
            'ACCOUNT_VERIFICATION',
            'CRMPicco.co.uk Account Email Verification'
        ]];
}
```

This is how the constant is declared inside `Mailer`:

```
const ACCOUNT_VERIFICATION = 'CRMPicco.co.uk Account Email Verification';
```

How can I check the value of this constant?

If I do `$mailer::ACCOUNT_VERIFICATION` inside the test it spits out the expected value, but I would like to do this dynamically with a dataProvider.

Comment: Can you show the declaration of the said constant in the `Mailer` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ClassName::$property` looks up the static property named `property` on `ClassName`, rather than the constant with the name stored in `$property`. PHP does not have a syntax for looking up constants named by string variables; you need to use the class reference in conjunction with the [`constant()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function.

For example:

```
/**
 * @dataProvider constantValueDataProvider
 */
public function testConstantValues(string $constant, $expectedValue)
{
    $classWithConstant = sprintf('%s::%s', Mailer::class, $constant);
    $this->assertEquals($expectedValue, constant($classWithConstant));
}
```

This is also possible with [reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstant.php), but with more code.

Comment: Thanks, yes I tried using `constant` initially but this led to the same error (and I tried with and without `ReflectionClass`.

Comment: @crmpicco I update my answer, you need to reference to it with the class name. Is possible in your scenario?